# Handling nested promises

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I am trying to reject a value inside a nested promise but it doesn't seem to actually reject it correctly. In the code below, when I get an error from promiseVariable, it doesn't reject with the error. In the promiseVariable.catch statement, I have reject(err). Shouldn't that reject with that error for the whole promise?

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const user = anotherFunction();
  if (!user) {
     promiseVariable.then((data) => {
       user = data;
     }).catch((err) => {
       reject(err)
     })
 }
 resolve(user);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it will start the `promiseVariable` chain and jump over to `resolve`. In the `.then`, you should resolve there, or put an `else`.

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const user = anotherFunction();
  if (!user) {
    promiseVariable
    .then(resolve)
    .catch(reject);
  } else {
    resolve(user);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're over-promising, if that's a word. You can just `"await"` for your other promise to complete.

Here, `anotherFunction` is a simulated Promise, where after 3 seconds it returns a valid object for your conditional `if(!user)`.

You can try changing `resolve({user: 1234})` with a false (or falsy) value to see its rejection.

```js
function anotherFunction() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve({user: 1234}), 3000)
    });
}

async function mainFunction() {
    const user = await anotherFunction();
    return user || {error: 404};
}

mainFunction().then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: I can't do new Promise(async (resolve,reject) {... because my linter doesn't allow the function to be async inside the new Promise.

Comment: @siri, well, next time remember to specify those limitations in your question so we can understand you completely.

Comment: Didn't know it was a constraint until I tried your solution. However, is there any other way I can do what you propose? It seems to be cleaner

Comment: Well, if you can get rid of the promise inside `mainFunction` (in my example), it surely can be cleaner.

Comment: @siri I edited my code, I think that's what you're looking for. Let me know if it helped.